# Angular service worker is in SAFE_MODE

Tags: angular, angular7, angular-service-worker

I have an Angular PWA. Its service worker was working flawlessly until I upgraded from Angular 5.0 to 7.2

After the upgrade, I see the following **error** in `/ngsw/state`

```
Driver state: SAFE_MODE (Initialization failed due to error: Invariant violated (initialize): latest hash null has no known
manifest initialize/<@https://{{domain}}.com/ngsw-worker.js:2227:27
fulfilled@https://{{domain}}.com/ngsw-worker.js:1772:52 ) Latest
manifest hash: none Last update check: never
```

**App background**

- Angular version is 7.2.0
- Service worker version is 7.2.0
- I am manually checking for updates using SwUpdate service.

**Code to check for updates**

```
if (this.updates.isEnabled) {
      const appIsStable$ = this.appRef.isStable.pipe(first(isStable => isStable === true));
      const every21600Ms$ = interval(6 * 60 * 60);
      const every21600MsOnceAppIsStable$ = concat(appIsStable$, every21600Ms$);
      // poll the service worker to check for updates
      every21600MsOnceAppIsStable$.subscribe(() =>
        this.updates.checkForUpdate()
      );
    }
```

**My research and troubleshooting steps so far:**

***In Chrome***

- Service worker is registered without any error
- I looked into the network tab and found service worker never downloads 'ngsw.json'. I have seen 'ngsw.json' being downloaded when the app was in Angular 5.0

[image: Screenshot1]

- I see the same issue has been reported [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/25611). I don't see any proper solution here.
- I have tried selecting 'Update on reload' which fixes the problem temporarily. Same error shows up again after I unselect it.

[image: Screenshot2]

***In Microsoft edge***

- Surprisingly, everything works in edge after the upgrade.

**My thoughts and expectations**

- Since the application is working fine in MS edge, I doubt that there is anything wrong with service worker config or with the way I poll for updates
- My expectation is to see Drive state as Normal in /ngsw/state

Comment: If it could help, there is an open issue on [angular/angular](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/25611) about this problem.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I have seen this link earlier. The issue is still open :(

Answer (score 2):

## Update

This will be fixed as of Angular version 8.2.14. Below workarounds are only required with older versions.

---

## Old workarounds for < 8.2.14

It seems this is a well known bug in the Angular service worker and that we may expect a patch / working version at some point. Most information can be found in [issue 25611](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/25611) as [shobhit vaish](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5468755/shobhit-vaish) already stated.

However, if you are looking for a solution now or you are going to stick with an older Angular 7/8 version longer, which maybe will not get patched soon, I will try to sum up the currently known workarounds. (Also they may not qualify as "proper solution"...)

## Patching `ngsw-worker.js`

You can patch your `ngsw-worker.js` file either after your `ng run app:build:production` where it will typically reside in the `www` folder inside your project (if you haven't changed the Angular `outputPath`). Or you can patch it before your build inside `node_modules/@angular/service-worker`.

Depending on how often you build your app you could do it simply manually (i.e. with a text editor of your choice) or you write a script for example with the help of [sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html).

Now you have two options:

### 1. Patching `handleMessage()`

Search for

```
        handleMessage(msg, from) {
            return __awaiter$5(this, void 0, void 0, function* () {
```

And replace it with

```
        handleMessage(msg, from) {
            return __awaiter$5(this, void 0, void 0, function* () {
                if (this.initialized === null) {
                    this.initialized = this.initialize();
                }
                try {
                    yield this.initialized;
                }
                catch (e) {
                    this.state = DriverReadyState.SAFE_MODE;
                    this.stateMessage = `Initialization failed due to handleMessage() error: ${errorToString(e)}`;
                }
```

Depending on your `@angular/service-worker` version the signature of `handleMessage()` may look different for you and you could write a more sophisticated `catch` but hopefully / probably it would never reach the `catch` block anyways.
This patch basically is what is suggested in [a comment by gkalpak](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/25611#issuecomment-464756987) and most likely the official fix will also be something like this.

### 2. Patching `initialize()`

Search for

```
                try {
                    // Read them from the DB simultaneously.
                    [manifests, assignments, latest] = yield Promise.all([
                        table.read('manifests'),
                        table.read('assignments'),
                        table.read('latest'),
                    ]);
```

And replace it with

```
                try {
                    // Read them from the DB simultaneously.
                    [manifests, assignments, latest] = yield Promise.all([
                        table.read('manifests'),
                        table.read('assignments'),
                        table.read('latest'),
                    ]);
                    if (latest.latest === null) throw new Error('Error latest.latest is null for what ever reason...');
```

With this you will ensure that the `catch` block of `initialize()` will actually run and prevent the service worker from entering `SAFE_MODE`. However this may not be as reliable as the first patch but could also work for service workers which are already in `SAFE_MODE` due to this problem. It was proposed in [a comment by hsta](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/25611#issuecomment-514404035).

## Working around the problem in your Angular app

If you don't want to mess around with the `ngsw-worker.js` you can try to detect the state of the service worker by fetching `your-app.domain/ngsw/state` from within your Angular app and if it is in `SAFE_MODE` (could be checked for example with a simple `regex` search) you can try to reset it by deleting all items from the cache storage and then unregistering the service worker. The idea to this was proposed in [a comment by mattlewis92](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/25611#issuecomment-515468960) and approved as probably working hack in [a comment by gkalpak](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/25611#issuecomment-515509959).

## Temporary working around the problem manually

As [shobhit vaish](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5468755/shobhit-vaish) already found out, you can also manually resolve the issue. Next to the possibility which is already stated in the original post you can also do this in the dev tools of chrome based browser under "Application" -> "Clear storage", selecting "Unregister service workers" and hit "Clear site data". Obviously the problem can and probably will come back on future updates and will not help much for normal users. But it may be handy if you as developer just want to resolve it quickly at the moment.